# Deleting multiple items with a single click in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to delete items from the cart but i need to delete them in multiple so i created an array ids and use push to add the id of items i want to delete to the array  when a user checked a checkbox  so i can process everything on button click, but when i click on `submit` i got error ids.push is not a function, can anyone help me out on this or even a better of achieving the same function. below is my code sample
[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sammyzeal/x7mys0ac/4/)

in the fiddle below when i click on the yes button i get 1 always how can i make it so when i check a checkbox i will get the data-id.

```js
var ids = [];
$(".delCartCheck").click(function() {
  id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  ids = ids.push(id);
});

$('#confirm-delete').on('click', function(e) {
  alert(ids);

  function deletecart(ids) {

    $.ajax({
      url: delUrl,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        id: ids
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (data === 'success') {
          window.location = url + data;
        } else {
          window.location = url + data;
        }
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, errMsg) {
        // handle error
        console.log(errMsg);
      }
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pull_left checkbox-wrap itemDel" title="delete item">
  <label class="check_container " style="top:40px;">
           <input type="checkbox" class="delCartCheck" data-id="1">
           <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
</div>
<div class="pull_left checkbox-wrap itemDel" title="delete item">
  <label class="check_container " style="top:40px;">
             <input type="checkbox" class="delCartCheck" data-id="2">
             <span class="checkmark"></span>
       </label>
</div>
<div class="pull_left checkbox-wrap itemDel" title="delete item">
  <label class="check_container " style="top:40px;">
          <input type="checkbox" class="delCartCheck" data-id="3">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
</div>

<button type="button" id='confirm-delete'>Yes</button>
<button type="button" class="">No</button>
```

Comment: `push` returns the new length of the array, not the array itself.

Comment: Is this what you want Sam ? https://jsfiddle.net/x7mys0ac/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way: https://jsfiddle.net/x7mys0ac/46/

if checked checkbox, **push** data-id else **splice** to remove an element from an array.

```
var ids = [];
$(".delCartCheck").click(function() {
  if($(this).prop("checked")){
        ids.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
  } else{
       var x = ids.indexOf($(this).attr('data-id'));
       ids.splice(x,1);
   }
  console.log(ids)
});

$('#confirm-delete').on('click', function(e) {
var newArray = ids.filter(function(v){return v!==''});
alert(newArray)
  function deletecart(ids) {

    $.ajax({
      url: delUrl,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        id: ids
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (data === 'success') {
          window.location = url + data;
        } else {
          window.location = url + data;
        }
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, errMsg) {
        // handle error
        console.log(errMsg);
      }
    });
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here ids = ids.push(id) assigns the value returned by ids.push() to ids.

```
$(".delCartCheck").click(function() {
      id = $(this).attr('data-id');
      ids = ids.push(id);
    });
```

What you're looking for is this :

```
$(".delCartCheck").click(function() {
      id = $(this).attr('data-id');
      ids.push(id);
    });
```

Comment: If multiple checkboxes are checked, for example checkbox 1 and 3 it will only display: 3 not sure if this intended by @Sam

Comment: @Boo thanks a lot that seems to do the trick, please one more question, How do i remove the ids from the array if a user uncheck the checkbox

Comment: [`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the array at that position.

Comment: Here copy and paste in jsfiddle :
`$(".delCartCheck").click(function() {
  id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  if($.inArray(id, ids) !=-1) {
   ids.splice($.inArray(id, ids),1);
  } else ids.push(id);

});`

Or see here (https://jsfiddle.net/x7mys0ac/37/)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are assign `push` method return status to variable `ids = ids.push(id);`

`ids = ids.push(id);` this is not return the array but the status true or false. so true mean its 1. so `ids==1` then ids became a normal variable not an array. so for normal array there are no `push` function.

try something like this:

```
var ids = [];
$(".delCartCheck").click(function() {  
  ids = [];
  $(".delCartCheck:checked").each(function(){
    id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    ids.push(id);
  });  
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x7mys0ac/41/