# How to remove multiple cart items on one click in shopify?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, shopify, cart

On Shopify cart page we can see multiple cart items if we added. Dawn Theme give functionality to remove each cart item separately. Is there any way to remove multiple cart Items by selecting them and click on delete, then all the selected items should be removed?
Below is my code I tried by the reference of [Bhumi Shah's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51019200/deleting-multiple-items-with-a-single-click-in-javascript) answer. But I get selected values in console but can't able to delete them. [Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/ySvOu358dhUl)

```js
var ids = [];
  $(".delCartCheck").click(function() {
    if($(this).prop("checked")){
      ids.push($(this).attr('data-check-id'));
    } else{
      var x = ids.indexOf($(this).attr('data-check-id'));
      ids.splice(x,1);
    }
    console.log(ids)
  });

  $('#confirm-delete').on('click', function(e) {
    //       debugger;
    var newArray = ids.filter(function(v){return v!==''});
    //       alert(newArray);

    function deletecart(ids) {

      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/cart/clear.js',
        data: {
          id: ids
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if (data === 'success') {
            $(newArray).parents(".cart-item").remove();
          }
        }
      });
    }


  });
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
 <button type="button btn" id='confirm-delete'>Delete Selected Item</button>

<form action="{{ routes.cart_url }}" class="cart__contents critical-hidden" method="post" id="cart">
  <div class="cart__items" id="main-cart-items" data-id="{{ section.id }}">
  {%- if cart != empty -%}
  <table class="cart-items">
    <tbody>
      {%- for item in cart.items -%}
      <tr class="cart-item" id="CartItem-{{ item.index | plus: 1 }}">
        <td class="cart-item__media">
          <input type="checkbox" class="delCartCheck" data-check-id="{{forloop.index}}">
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  {% endif %}
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: refresh the cart design table after removing cart item by index

Comment: you need also pass the quantity 0 along with ID, to clear from the cart

Comment: I tried to use quantity with variant ID but It's not working properly. Also I change ajax url to url: '/cart/clear.js' now It remove all the cart Items from the cart after refresh the page. All I want is without refreshing the page cart Items should update. Can you update my script?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://shopify.dev/api/ajax/reference/cart#post-locale-cart-update-js) and modify the code according to the required structure
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer, but including the technical details using a picture of text rather than actual text will not be immediately helpful to any of our friends using assistive technologies such as screen readers, etc. Would you be able to quote or transcribe the most important parts into your answer? :)